# How do i get CUDA working with VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cuda

Ok i havent used CUDA before, i was hoping to get started on it using VS2010.

Ive run the bandwidth test and ive got everything installed (i believe). I also have NProfiler installed.

But im not too sure what i have to do to start coding CUDA in VS2010. I have been googling around but everything seems aimed at VS2008.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, we still use VS2008 to compile our CUDA applications because NVIDIA still have a lot of work to do to integrate things well under VS2010.

Anyway, if you need help to compile CUDA apps under VS2008, you can check [this post](http://codereflect.com/2008/09/26/how-to-integrate-cuda-with-visual-c/).

If you would like to insist on VS2010, [this guy](http://www.ademiller.com/blogs/tech/2010/08/getting-cuda-3-1-working-with-visual-studio-2010/) seems to have succeeded with CUDA 3.1.

Comment: Hey, say i just want to write CUDA applications but not in Visual Studio, what am i supposed to use to compile?

Comment: @Tom Great question. Make it official and start a new thread.